# Reverse DNS lookup in perl

Tags: perl, ip, lookup, nslookup, reverse-dns

How do I perform a reverse DNS lookup, that is how do I resolve an IP address to its DNS hostname in Perl?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

gethostbyaddr and similar calls. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gethostbyaddr.html

Answer (score 22):

If you need more detailed DNS info use the [Net::DNS](http://search.cpan.org/~olaf/Net-DNS-0.63/lib/Net/DNS.pm) module, here is an example:

```
use Net::DNS;
my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;

# create the reverse lookup DNS name (note that the octets in the IP address need to be reversed).
my $IP = "209.85.173.103";
my $target_IP = join('.', reverse split(/\./, $IP)).".in-addr.arpa";

my $query = $res->query("$target_IP", "PTR");

if ($query) {
  foreach my $rr ($query->answer) {
    next unless $rr->type eq "PTR";
    print $rr->rdatastr, "\n";
  }
} else {
  warn "query failed: ", $res->errorstring, "\n";
}
```

Original Source [EliteHackers.info](https://www.elitehackers.info/forums/archive/index.php/t-824.html), more details there as well.

Answer (score 17):

```
use Socket;
$iaddr = inet_aton("127.0.0.1"); # or whatever address
$name  = gethostbyaddr($iaddr, AF_INET);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -MSocket -E 'say scalar gethostbyaddr(inet_aton("69.89.27.250"), AF_INET)'
```

Returns: **Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.**

```
perl -MSocket -E "say scalar gethostbyaddr(inet_aton(\"69.89.27.250\"), AF_INET)"
```

Returns: **box250.bluehost.com**

I have to change the line to use double quotes and then escape out the quotes around the IP address

Comment: That's probably because you're using cmd.exe under windows.

Answer (score 2):

one-liner:

```
perl -MSocket -E 'say scalar gethostbyaddr(inet_aton("79.81.152.79"), AF_INET)'
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way, but for IPv4, if you can perform ordinary DNS lookups, you can always construct the reverse query yourself. For the IPv4 address A.B.C.D, look up any PTR records at D.C.B.A.in-addr.arpa. For IPv6, you take the 128 hex nibbles and flip them around and append ipv6.arpa. and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If gethostbyaddr doesn't fit your needs, [Net::DNS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::DNS) is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful...

```
$ip = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" # IPV4 address.
my @numbers = split (/\./, $ip);
if (scalar(@numbers) != 4)
{
    print "$ip is not a valid IP address.\n";
    next;
}
my $ip_addr = pack("C4", @numbers);
# First element of the array returned by gethostbyaddr is host name.
my ($name) = (gethostbyaddr($ip_addr, 2))[0];
```