# NGINX + PERL > trying to create a reverse DNS variable

Tags: perl, nginx, dns

Based on [Reverse DNS lookup in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85487/reverse-dns-lookup-in-perl) i tried to create a variable in NGINX so I can use in order to identify search engines but I got alot of errors like this:

> 2016/06/16 21:10:33 [error] 25853#0: *519 call_sv("sub { return scalar
>   gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($remote_addr), AF_INET); }") failed:
>   "Undefined subroutine &main::inet_aton called at (eval 3) line 1."

Added into my http block:

```
perl_require Socket.pm;
perl_set $test_rdns "sub { return scalar gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($remote_addr), AF_INET); }";
```

Please help, I can't find the key of solving this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what `perl_require` does, but I reckon it has something to do with Perl's `require` function, and a thing to be wary of when you use `require` is that it does not call the package's `import` method and does not load the default exported functions and symbols into the calling package.

The upshot is you would have to use qualified symbol names in your Perl call

```
perl_set $test_rdns "sub { return scalar gethostbyaddr(Socket::inet_aton($remote_addr), \
                                                       Socket::AF_INET); }";
```

or you will have to call `Socket`'s `import` method

```
perl_set $test_rdns "sub { use Socket; return scalar \
                gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($remote_addr), AF_INET); }";
```

(This second suggestion is not tested, and may not work depending on what nginx does with perl's library directories and search path)